# AWS Kinesis Consumer Python 3.4 Boto

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-sdk

I am trying to build a kinesis consumer script using python 3.4 below is an example of my code. I want the records to be saved to a local file that I can later push to S3:

```
from boto import kinesis
import time
import json

# AWS Connection Credentials
aws_access_key = 'your_key'
aws_access_secret = 'your_secret key'

# Selected Kinesis Stream
stream = 'TwitterTesting'

# Aws Authentication
auth = {"aws_access_key_id": aws_access_key, "aws_secret_access_key": aws_access_secret}
conn = kinesis.connect_to_region('us-east-1',**auth)

# Targeted file to be pushed to S3 bucket
fileName = "KinesisDataTest2.txt"
file = open("C:\\Users\\csanders\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\KinesisDataTest.txt", "a")

# Describe stream and get shards
tries = 0
while tries < 10:
    tries += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    response = conn.describe_stream(stream)
    if response['StreamDescription']['StreamStatus'] == 'ACTIVE':
        break
else:
    raise TimeoutError('Stream is still not active, aborting...')

# Get Shard Iterator and get records from stream
shard_ids = []
stream_name = None
if response and 'StreamDescription' in response:
    stream_name = response['StreamDescription']['StreamName']
    for shard_id in response['StreamDescription']['Shards']:
        shard_id = shard_id['ShardId']
        shard_iterator = conn.get_shard_iterator(stream,
        shard_id, 'TRIM_HORIZON')
        shard_ids.append({'shard_id': shard_id, 'shard_iterator': shard_iterator['ShardIterator']})
        tries = 0
        result = []
        while tries < 100:
            tries += 1
            response = conn.get_records(shard_iterator, 100)
            shard_iterator = response['NextShardIterator']
            if len(response['Records'])> 0:
                for res in response['Records']:
                    result.append(res['Data'])
                    print(result, shard_iterator)
```

For some reason when I run this script I get the following error each time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/csanders/PycharmProjects/untitled/Get_records_Kinesis.py",  line 57, in <module>
    response = json.load(conn.get_records(shard_ids, 100))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\boto-2.38.0-py3.4.egg\boto\kinesis\layer1.py", line 327, in get_records
    body=json.dumps(params))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\boto-2.38.0- py3.4.egg\boto\kinesis\layer1.py", line 874, in make_request
    body=json_body)
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{'Message': 'Start of list found where not expected', '__type':   'SerializationException'}
```

My end goal is to eventually kick this data into an S3 bucket. I just need to get these records to return and print first. The data going into the stream is JSON dump twitter data using the `put_record` function. I can post that code too if needed.

Updated that one line from response = json.load(conn.get_records(shard_ids, 100)) to response = conn.get_records(shard_iterator, 100)

Comment: The call to ``conn.get_records(..)`` is going to return a Python dictionary.  Why are you calling ``json.load()`` on it?

Comment: I have just been trying different things. When I don't use json.loads () I still get the exact same error message.

Comment: Did you base64 encode your content before storing it in Kinesis?

Comment: I'm a noob to all of this still, can you explain that to me? I can post the producer script as well if that helps. I got that to work and stream to Kinesis.

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is that you are passing an array of dictionaries in as the ``shard_iterator`` parameter but Kinesis is expecting a single string value.

Comment: Boto is doing the base64 encoding for you on the way in so that's fine.

Comment: I tried putting the shard_iterator into the function, and also tried putting it as a str, however I still got an error. boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{'__type': 'SerializationException', 'Message': 'Start of structure or map found where not expected.'}

Answer (score 0):

```
response = json.load(conn.get_records(shard_ids, 100))
```

get_records expects a shard_id not an array of shards. when it's trying to get records it fails miserably (you see the 400 from Kinesis saying that the request is bad).

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/kinesis.html?highlight=get_records#boto.kinesis.layer1.KinesisConnection.get_records

Comment: Put in a shard_ID and this was the error message, I also tried removing the json.load:Traceback (most recent call last):
 InvalidArgumentException: 400 Bad Request
{'message': 'Invalid ShardIterator.', '__type': 'InvalidArgumentException'}

Comment: do you get this on the first shard or on later shards? the iterators expire in 5 minutes

Comment: This is on the first shard. I have two test streams, one with one shard, and one with two. I get the same error regardless of which stream I am using. I have no problems printing out the shard iterator to console.

Comment: it's not the shard_id. It's the shard iterator. (shard_iterator in your code). The id is the shard name, the iterator is the actual pointer in the stream. you cannot get records without the iterator.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. I changed it to response = conn.get_records(shard_iterator, 100). Getting boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{'Message': 'Start of structure or map found where not expected.', '__type': 'SerializationException'} as the error message in that case.

Comment: Updated in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> if you replace following will work ( "while" you set up according for how many record you would like to collect, you can make infinite "with == 0" and remove "tries += 1")

```
    shard_iterator = conn.get_shard_iterator(stream,
    shard_id, 'TRIM_HORIZON')
    shard_ids.append({'shard_id': shard_id, 'shard_iterator': shard_iterator['ShardIterator']})
```

with following:

```
    shard_iterator = conn.get_shard_iterator(stream,
    shard_id, "LATEST")["ShardIterator"]
```

> also to write to a file change("\n" is for new line):

```
print(result, shard_iterator)
```

to:

```
file.write(str(result) + "\n")
```

Hope it helps.